# How to route to html file in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

I have a nodejs file with http module in my raspberry pi 3 server that takes value from database and write it into json file. In this situation, I need to take the value from json by using another js file and I'm using the values in my charm, in html. I run the files(the nodejs file and html file) in different ports. Is there any way to call the html file into nodejs?

SOLUTION: As I remember, I tried to ask how to run html file which is running in with python script with node server running on a port. The solution is simple, do not use python, give the html file as a response as dear Ernesto said, sorry for that bad beginner question:)

Comment: What do you mean with "I run the files in different ports?" and why are you saving the database query response into a JSON file to then load it again (and also the HTML file)? You'll have to provide more info about your files structure and execution environments.

Comment: Ideally, you'll have to listen to HTTP requests using the NodeJS HTTP module (or a framework like ExpressJS could be useful). Once you receive the request, the normal procedure would be to query the database, generate the HTML, set response headers and save serialized HTML document to the response body, finally sending it. No need to write/read any files. If you want to throttle down database requests or HTML generation, just use some catching strategy. Write/read operations are expensive.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano I tried to tell that I use `python3 -m http.server 8083 -b 10.0.3.57` and node chart.js(node file runs in 8080). I am beginner with nodejs, so I do not know how it works well, i'm struggling while trying to create an algorithm in nodejs... I'm open to suggestions

Comment: How are you running your Node script? Can you post your code? Database querying, HTML creation, etc.